# What is the best way to move two HTML elements around on a page with CSS so they overlap?

Tags: html, css, overlap

Whenever I want to be able to make two things overlap (like an image over another image or something), using margin or padding works but it can make other things not work properly (like text not going to the next line or not being able to make other things overlap anymore). I want to know this for future use in any project, not really a specific one so I don't have a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `position: relative` for both (or at least one of the) elements in question.

That does not affect the position of the other elements of that document, because is isn't removing the elements from the normal document flow.

The overlap of the relatively positioned elements is then realized by offsetting each of them relative to itself based on the values of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`.

CSS to make 2 divs overlap vertically 10px:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.overlap {
  position: relative;  
}

.overlap.one {
  bottom: -5px;
}

.overlap.two {
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div>Before</div>
<div class="one">Div One - without overlap</div>
<div class="two">Div Two - without overlap</div>
<div>After</div>
<hr>
<div>Before</div>
<div class="overlap one">Div One - overlapping downwards</div>
<div class="overlap two">Div Two - overlapping upwards</div>
<div>After</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: This answers my original question but would it work if there are multiple elements throughout the css with margins? I keep running into the problem where I can't move text as freely as I want to.

Comment: @5meagle I do not really understand what you mean in your comment exactly. Maybe you ask this in a separate question.